# Delete/Remove position of a list view when timer completes

Tags: android, listadapter, countdowntimer

I am using list view with each and every row has its own timer.I want to delete the position of a list view when timer is completed its time interval.I had implemented as below but position is always catching wrongly and last item is deleting every time.Please see my code below,inside onfinish() of timer i am  trying to remove the position but it is not getting deleted properly, help me.

ProductListAdapter.java

```
 package com.devpoint.adapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.devpoint.PlacesandMaps.GMapV2Direction;
import com.devpoint.PlacesandMaps.PlacesMapActivity;
import com.devpoint.common.GetAllGooglePlaces;
import com.devpoint.model.ListDetails;
import com.devpoint.rprtgnet.LoadActivity;
import com.devpoint.rprtgnet.MapFragmentActivity;
import com.devpoint.rprtgnet.R;
import com.devpoint.sharedpreferences.SharedPreference;
import com.devpoint.tabsswipe.ListOnGoing;
import com.devpoint.tabsswipe.SwipeViewPagerAdapter;
import com.devpoint.user.PostLogcatErrors;
import com.devpoint.volley.AppController;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.view.animation.Transformation;

@SuppressLint({ "InflateParams", "ShowToast" })
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListDetails> {

    private Activity context;
    List<ListDetails> products;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    public static com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader imageLoader;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //ViewHolder holder;
    protected String Day = ""; 
    public static View alertLayout;
    private static GMapV2Direction gmapdirection;
    public static GoogleMap gmap; 
    protected Document doc;
    static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 200;


    //TextView timer;

    //String Pagename;
     private HashMap<TextView,CountDownTimer> counters;

     static class TestViewHolder 
        {
            public TextView tvCounter;
        }

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<ListDetails> products) { 
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_offer_list_item, products);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.products = products;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

         this.counters = new HashMap<TextView, CountDownTimer>(); 

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView productNameTxt;
        //TextView Ratingsno;
        TextView productPriceTxt;
        //TextView timedist;
        TableLayout distancesection; 
        TextView categoryname;
        ImageView favoriteImg;
        RatingBar rb;
        ImageView OfferImage;
        //ImageView MapImage;
        ImageView listimage;
        public TextView distance;
        public ImageView indicator;
        TextView timer;

        TextView move;
        //TextView Postedon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListDetails getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position; 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int po, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        try {


            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Day = "";
            final ListDetails product = products.get(po);



            //final int abc = po;  

            /*LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offerlist_new, parent,
                        false);
                final View v= convertView;

                // convertView.requestLayout();
                holder.productNameTxt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.productPriceTxt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listview_description);
                holder.distance = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listview_distane);
                /*holder.timedist = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.timedist);*/
                /*holder.Ratingsno = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.Ratingsno);*/
                /*holder.Postedon = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.Postedon);*/
                holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.fav_checkbox);

                holder.rb = (RatingBar) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
                holder.timer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
                holder.categoryname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.Categoryname);
                holder.listimage = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                /*holder.distancesection = (TableLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.distancesection);*/

                /*holder.MapImage = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgmap);*/

                holder.move = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listview_description3);

                holder.move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            removeListItem(v,po) ;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            PostLogcatErrors ple = new PostLogcatErrors();
                            ple.PostLogcatErorrs(e);
                        }
                    }
                });

                String text = "<font color=#222222>" + product.getShopName()
                        + "</font>"
                        + "<small><font color=#0091EA> ( </font></small>"
                        + " <small><font color=#0091EA>" + product.getAreaName()
                        + "</font></small>"
                        + "<small><font color=#0091EA> ) </font></small>";
                holder.productNameTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

            // holder.productNameTxt.setText(product.getShopName() + "  " + "( "
            // + Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0091EA'>" + product.getAreaName()
            // + "</font>") + " )");
            holder.productPriceTxt.setText(product.getDeal() + "");
            holder.rb.setRating(Float.valueOf(product.getRatingAvg()));
            //holder.Ratingsno.setText(product.getTotalRatings() + " Ratings");
            //holder.timedist.setText(product.getTime());
            holder.distance.setText(String.valueOf(product.getDistance())
                    + " Km");
            holder.categoryname.setText(product.getCategoryName());
                //holder.listimage.setImageUrl(product.getListImage(), imageLoader);
                Picasso.with(context).load(product.getListImage()).into(holder.listimage); 



            if (checkFavoriteItem(product)) {
                holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                holder.favoriteImg.setTag(context
                        .getString(R.string.red_favcolor));
            } else {
                holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.unchecked);
                holder.favoriteImg.setTag(context
                        .getString(R.string.grey_favcolor)); 
            }
            /*holder.Postedon.setText("Posted On" + "  "
                    + product.getPostedDate());*/

                    final TextView tv = holder.timer;



                CountDownTimer cdt = counters.get(tv); 
                if(cdt!=null)
                {
                    cdt.cancel();
                    cdt=null;
                }

                cdt = new CountDownTimer(Long.parseLong(product.getOfferEndTime()), 1000)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                    {

                        int minutes = 0;
                        int seconds = 0;
                        String sDate = "";

                        if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
                        {
                            minutes = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
                        }

                        millisUntilFinished -= (minutes*DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

                        if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
                        {
                            seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                        }

                        sDate += " "+"00"+":"+String.format("%02d",minutes)+":"+String.format("%02d",seconds);
                        tv.setText(sDate.trim());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() { 

                        tv.setText("Finished");

                        final int abc = po; 




                         final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                                 context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);  
                         v.startAnimation(animation);
                         Handler handle = new Handler();
                         handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                             public void run() {

                                 products.remove(abc);
                                 ListOnGoing.productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(
                                        LoadActivity.activity, products); 
                                ListOnGoing.swipelisview
                                        .setAdapter(ListOnGoing.productListAdapter); 
                                ListOnGoing.productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                             } 
                         }, 1000); 






                    }
                };

                counters.put(tv, cdt);
                cdt.start();


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            return convertView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            PostLogcatErrors ple = new PostLogcatErrors();
            ple.PostLogcatErorrs(e);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    /* Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences */
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(ListDetails checkProduct) {
        boolean check = false;
        List<ListDetails> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (ListDetails product : favorites) {
                /*
                 * if (product.equals(checkProduct)) { check = true; break; }
                 */

                if (product.getOfferID().equals(checkProduct.getOfferID())) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }

    public void cancelAllTimers()
    {
        Set<Entry<TextView, CountDownTimer>> s = counters.entrySet();
        Iterator it = s.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                CountDownTimer cdt = (CountDownTimer)pairs.getValue();

                cdt.cancel();
                cdt = null;
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

        it=null;
        s=null;
        counters.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `abc` your class' field? Try making it local final int.

Comment: Yes abc is position and i declared it already private int, getting the issue @Poger

Answer (score 1):

If `abc` is declared as a field of your class (e. g. `private int abc`), you are assigning `po` to `abc` each time `getView` gets called. Later, when you call

```
products.remove(abc);
```

You are removing an element with index of the last assigned value of `abc`, which most probably is index of the last element.

Replace the above line with

```
products.remove(po);
```

or change

```
abc = po;
```

to

```
final int abc = po;
```

Also try doing a similar thing with the following line:

```
holder = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination @Poger ,even if i changed this field as final int my output remains same as previous

Comment: please help me regarding this issue @poger

Comment: What should i do with holder =null;? @Poger

Comment: please find me out where i am doing mistake

Comment: Please help me i stucked on this since morning

Comment: Thank you @Harikrishna for posting your full code. I'm sorry, but unfortunately I can't find what's wrong with your code at the moment. I was pretty sure that what I wrote earlier would fix your problem. I suggest to debug your application and put breakpoints on the essential lines (like removing a row, assigning position) and check what values are being passed/assigned. It could point you to a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Poger